# Printing the Object Arrays As a String

Tags: java

I want to print the object array as a string. here is my code.
 I have followed instructions in this page but could not get it. `https://www.java67.com/2014/03/how-to-print-array-in-java-example-tutorial.html`

```
class Tiger extends Animal implements Comparable<Tiger>
{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tiger t)
    {

        return this.stripes-t.stripes;
    }
    int stripes;
    Tiger(String color,String name,int stripes)
    {
        super(color,name);
        this.stripes=stripes;
    }
    @Override
    void move()
    {
        System.out.println("Tiger moving");
    }


}
class Main1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Tiger[] tigers={new Tiger("red","tiger_1",12),
                        new Tiger("red","tiger_2",8),
                        new Tiger("red","tiger_3",10)};
        Arrays.sort(tigers);

        System.out.println( Arrays.toString(tigers));



    }
}
```

I have tried Arrays.toString. but the output is a quite like this : `[Tiger@7d4991ad, Tiger@28d93b30, Tiger@1b6d3586]`

Comment: Override the `toString()` method in your `Tiger` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the toString class inside the Tiger class. and whatever info you want to print of a tiger object just return the info as string. Then this string will be printed whenever you print a tiger class. For example the following implementation of toString will print the name property of a tiger object.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.name:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `toString()` of `Tiger` to customize the default implementation. Something ike:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Tiger{name=" + name + ", color=" + color + ", stripes=" + stripes + "}";
}
```

assuming `name` and `color` are inherited from `Animal`.

Answer (score 0):

First you should override `toString()` in class `Tiger`

```
Class Tiger{
....
..

@override
public String toString(){

  return name+" "+ color;
}

}
```

then you can use `tiger.toString`

Comment: @ShreeshBhat if it helps you please upvote my answer so that it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Override toString() in Tiger class

```
import java.util.*;
class Tiger implements Comparable<Tiger>
{
      @Override
      public int compareTo(Tiger t)
        {

            return this.stripes-t.stripes;
    }

    int stripes;
    String color;
    String name;

    Tiger(String color,String name,int stripes)
    {
        this.color=color;
        this.name=name;
        this.stripes=stripes;


    }

     @Override
     public String toString()
         {
             return color + " " + name + " " + stripes;
    }




}





public class Main1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Tiger[] tigers={new Tiger("red","tiger_1",12),
                        new Tiger("red","tiger_2",8),
                        new Tiger("red","tiger_3",10)};


         Arrays.sort(tigers);

        System.out.println( Arrays.toString(tigers));



    }
}
```

Ouptput:-

> **[red tiger_2 8, red tiger_3 10, red tiger_1 12]**